# JPA Entity how to do it

Tags: java, jpa

I have those entities
When I persist the LotPaiement entity I want the idLot of PaiementId to be updated with  LotPaiement id .Is it possible?  I tried to use JoinColomn and others things but It's not working. I hope someone have another idea.....

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "XX", schema = "X")
    public class LotPaiement implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_LOT_PAIE_EXT", insertable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NO_ORGA", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String noOrganisme;

    @Column(name = "NO_FICH_BANQ", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String noFichierBanque;

    @Column(name = "NOM_FICH_BANQ" ,nullable = false, length = 60 )
    private String nomFichierBanque;

    @Column(name = "DAT_PROD", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date dateProdBanque;

    @Column(name = "IND_ENCAI", nullable = false, length = 1)
    @Convert(converter = CodeChoixJpaConverter.class)
    private CodeChoix encaissee = CodeChoix.NON;

    @Column(name = "COD_PROVEN", nullable = false, length = 1)
    private String codeProvenance;

    @Column(name = "NB_PAIE", nullable = false)
    private int nombrePaiements;

    @Column(name = "MONT_LOT_PAIE", nullable = false, precision = 12)
    private BigDecimal montantPaiements;

    @Column(name = "MONT_FRAIS_LOT_PAIE", nullable = false, precision = 12)
    private BigDecimal montantFraisPaiements;

    @Column(name = "NB_CORR", nullable = false)
    private int nombreCorrections;

    @Column(name = "MONT_CORR", nullable = false, precision = 12)
    private BigDecimal montantCorrections;

    @Column(name = "MONT_FRAIS_CORR", nullable = false, precision = 12)
    private BigDecimal montantFraisCorrections;

    @Column(name = "NO_USAG_CREA", length = 8)
    private String noUsagerCreation;

    @Column(name = "DAT_HRE_CREA", nullable = false, length = 26, insertable = false)
    private Date dateHeureCreation;

    @Column(name = "NO_USAG_MODIF", length = 8)
    private String noUsagerModif;

    @Column(name = "DAT_HRE_MODIF", nullable = false, length = 26, insertable = false)
    private Date dateHeureModif;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Paiement.class, mappedBy = "id.idLot", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Paiement> paiements = new ArrayList<Paiement>();
```

And  this one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "F_PAIEMENT_EXT" , schema = "PAX")
public class Paiement  implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 973636294796000052L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PaiementId id;

    @Column(name = "COD_TYP_TRANS", nullable = false, length = 1)
    @Convert(converter = TypeTransactionJpaConverter.class)
    private TypeTransaction codeTypeTransaction;

    @Column(name = "NOM_PAYEUR", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nomPayeur;

    @Column(name = "REFERENCE_1", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String reference1;

    @Column(name = "REFERENCE_2", length = 50)
    private String reference2;

    @Column(name = "MONT_PAIE", nullable = false, precision = 10)
    private BigDecimal montantPaiement;

    @Column(name = "MONT_FRAIS_PAIE", nullable = false, precision = 5)
    private BigDecimal montantFrais;

    @Column(name = "COD_TYP_ORIG", length = 1)
    @Convert(converter = TypeOrigineJpaConverter.class)
    private TypeOrigine codeTypeOrigine;

    @Column(name = "NO_INST_FINA", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private String noInstitutionFinanciere;

    @Column(name = "NO_TRANSIT_INST", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private String noTransitInstitution;

    @Column(name = "NO_CENTRE_SERV", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private String noCentreService;

    @Column(name = "DAT_PAIE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date datePaiement;

    @Column(name = "NO_USAG_CREA", length = 8)
    private String noUsagerCreation;

    @Column(name = "DAT_HRE_CREA", nullable = false, length = 26, insertable = false)
    private Date dateHeureCreation;

    @Column(name = "NO_USAG_MODIF", length = 8)
    private String noUsagerModif;

    @Column(name = "DAT_HRE_MODIF", nullable = false, length = 26, insertable = false)
    private Date dateHeureModif;
```

and this is the embeddable class

```
@Embeddable
public class PaiementId implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4993016053388314553L;

    @Column(name = "ID_LOT_PAIE_EXT")
    private int idLot;

    @Column(name = "NO_LIGNE", nullable = false)
    private int noLigne;
```

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: for the moment persist the LotPaiement and after the Paiement entity

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Is your ID value generated by the database, and you want that ID populated back to your entity after an insert?

Answer (score 1):

Your post is tagged with "JPA", so you are using an Object-Relational-Mapping framework, whose purpose is *precisely* to help you get rid of silly ids and replace them with actual references to objects.

So, your field should not be `private int idLot;`

It should be `private LotPaiement lotPaiament;`

And then of course the mapping will not work, you will need to fix it as follows:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Paiement.class, mappedBy = "lotPaiament", 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Paiement> paiements = new ArrayList<Paiement>();
```

Comment: Okok but when I persist my LotPaiement with is Paiement the lotPaiement in the paiementId is null and a get this SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: Well, it should not be null.  You have to set it to point to the right LotPaiement.  Just as you would have had to set the idLot to the id of the right LotPaiement if you were using ids.  It cannot magically figure out which object to refer to.  BTW, have you tried `private PaiementId id = new PaiementId();`?  Because the problem may be that the `id` is `null`.